# Error! on cannot find temp file for multiple uploads in PHP

Tags: php, html, input, upload

I want to upload two different files with different input file options. I think I am using the standard method in order to upload files and copy to different folder. Once files are uploaded it should be in `/temp` folder from where it can be copied to different folder. With the following code I can only look for one file in temp and it is successfully copied to the desired foler. The file which was able to copied was the second upload file. However, there is no temp file created for the first upload file. And PHP is not giving any error. Any sugestion? I am unable to identify what is the problem in the following code:

```
 <form>
Select File:
<input type="file" name="file[]" id= "file[]" maxlength="90" />         
Select  file2: 
<input type="file" name="file[]"  id= "file[]" maxlength="90"/>     
<input  type="submit" name = "submit"  value="Submit"/>

 <?php

if(isset($_FILES["file"])) {
print_r( $_FILES );
$target_dir = "upload/";
echo '<br>';
$no_files = count($_FILES["file"]['name']);


for ($i = 0; $i < $no_files; $i++) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"][$i] > 0) {
            echo '<br>'. $i;
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i] . "<br>";

    }else {
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]);
        $extension = end($temp);
             move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]);
            echo "<br><font color='green'>".$_FILES["file"]["name"][$i] . " Uploaded Successfully.</font><br>";            
    }
}
}


?>
</form>
```

Comment: How does your form looks like?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your HTML form ist wrong and you don't use array form name.

From PHP Manual:

html client side:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>Pictures:
        <input type="file" name="pictures[]" />
        <input type="file" name="pictures[]" />
        <input type="file" name="pictures[]" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </p>
</form>
```

And on server side:

```
<?php
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "data/$name");
    }
}
```

See more on [PHP.net](https://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)